# Restore default Toad layout

Tags: toad

I'm using Toad 6.1
Something happened to my client and now I don't see that nice layout I had before. All forms are Tabbed and etc.
Could someone tell me how to restore settings to defaults?
Thanks
P.S. I tried to use Configuration Wizard and option Default but it did not fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never found an easy way to "go back" to what I've had after restoring Toad. Here's a guide that gives some help:

http://www.brainsurface.com/articles/ToadTipsTricksExpertInsight.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I somehow changed my default view and couldn't see any data.

What solved my issue was:
- Click the "Browser Style" icon. It looks like a little menu icon with three check boxes. 
- Click "Toggle RHS Visibility."